# TileEntitySpecialRenderer’s isGlobalRenderer() method is ignored

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I’m making a mod for Minecraft 1.12. In it I have a tile entity that holds a list of block positions. I want to render a box in the world at each position specified in this list, a bit like how structure blocks display air blocks.

I managed to render the boxes by copying relevent code in TileEntityStructureRenderer but whenever the block associated to the tile entity exits the screen, all boxes stop rendering. I saw on some forums and in TileEntityStructureRenderer’s code that I should override `isGlobalRenderer()` method and make it return `true`. So I did, but the problem still persists and I have absolutely no clue as why. I looked up Forge’s docs but there isn’t any information on this that I could find.

Did I miss something? Maybe I’m registering the renderer the wrong way?

Here’s how I register my tile entity and its renderer in my mod’s class (I removed irrelevent code):

```java
@Mod(modid = NaissanceE.MODID, name = NaissanceE.NAME, version = NaissanceE.VERSION)
public class NaissanceE {
  public static final String MODID = "naissancee";
  public static final String NAME = "NaissanceE";
  public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

  @Mod.EventHandler
  public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
    if (event.getSide() == Side.CLIENT) {
      ClientRegistry.bindTileEntitySpecialRenderer(TileEntityLightOrbController.class, new TileEntityLightOrbControllerRenderer());
    }
  }

  @Mod.EventBusSubscriber
  static class EventsHandler {
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerBlocks(RegistryEvent.Register<Block> event) {
      GameRegistry.registerTileEntity(TileEntityLightOrbController.class, new ResourceLocation(MODID, "light_orb_controller"));
    }
}
```

and the code for the renderer (imports removed for clarity):

```java
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public class TileEntityLightOrbControllerRenderer extends TileEntitySpecialRenderer<TileEntityLightOrbController> {
  @Override
  public void render(TileEntityLightOrbController te, double x, double y, double z, float partialTicks, int destroyStage, float alpha) {
    EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;

    if ((player.canUseCommandBlock() || player.isSpectator())
        && (player.getHeldItemMainhand().getItem() == ModItems.LIGHT_ORB_TWEAKER
        || player.getHeldItemOffhand().getItem() == ModItems.LIGHT_ORB_TWEAKER)) {
      Tessellator tessellator = Tessellator.getInstance();
      BufferBuilder bufferbuilder = tessellator.getBuffer();
      GlStateManager.disableFog();
      GlStateManager.disableLighting();
      GlStateManager.disableTexture2D();
      GlStateManager.enableBlend();
      GlStateManager.tryBlendFuncSeparate(GlStateManager.SourceFactor.SRC_ALPHA, GlStateManager.DestFactor.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GlStateManager.SourceFactor.ONE, GlStateManager.DestFactor.ZERO);
      this.setLightmapDisabled(true);

      List<PathCheckpoint> checkpoints = te.getCheckpoints();
      for (int i = 0, size = checkpoints.size(); i < size; i++) {
        PathCheckpoint checkpoint = checkpoints.get(i);
        this.renderCheckpoint(te, x, y, z, checkpoint, tessellator, bufferbuilder);
      }

      this.setLightmapDisabled(false);
      GlStateManager.glLineWidth(1F);
      GlStateManager.enableLighting();
      GlStateManager.enableTexture2D();
      GlStateManager.enableDepth();
      GlStateManager.depthMask(true);
      GlStateManager.enableFog();
    }
  }

  private void renderCheckpoint(TileEntityLightOrbController te, double x, double y, double z, PathCheckpoint checkpoint, Tessellator tessellator, BufferBuilder bufferBuilder) {
    GlStateManager.glLineWidth(3f);
    bufferBuilder.begin(3, DefaultVertexFormats.POSITION_COLOR);
    BlockPos tePos = te.getPos();
    BlockPos checkpointPos = checkpoint.getPos();

    final double size = 0.25;
    double start = 0.5 - size;
    double end = 0.5 + size;
    double x1 = checkpointPos.getX() - tePos.getX() + start + x;
    double y1 = checkpointPos.getY() - tePos.getY() + start + y;
    double z1 = checkpointPos.getZ() - tePos.getZ() + start + z;
    double x2 = checkpointPos.getX() - tePos.getX() + end + x;
    double y2 = checkpointPos.getY() - tePos.getY() + end + y;
    double z2 = checkpointPos.getZ() - tePos.getZ() + end + z;

    int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    if (checkpoint.isStop()) {
      r = 1;
    } else {
      g = 1;
    }

    RenderGlobal.drawBoundingBox(bufferBuilder, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, r, g, b, 1);

    tessellator.draw();
  }

  // FIXME ignored
  @Override
  public boolean isGlobalRenderer(TileEntityLightOrbController te) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The full code is available [here](https://github.com/Darmo117/NaissanceE_Minecraft_mod/tree/master/src/main/java/net/darmo_creations/naissancee).

Answer (score 0):

So, I just found out that for some reason it seems to not work when I run the game through Intellij but works fine when launching the game through the official laucher…